# Связан ли как то gcm и google logIn кнопка?

Tags: java, android, google-authenticator

Мне нужно получить tokenId при гугл логине и все работает, если я использую свой аккаунт гугл разработчика, но как только я переключаю на другой аккаунт разработчика то:

```
Error 12501 authenticating
```

Я думаю может как-то связана моя имплементация GCM и гугл кнопка?

Надеюсь не сильно запутанно объяснил, если что-то нужно дополнить - спрашивайте!

Спасибо

**Правка**

Инициализация GCM

```
public class RegisterGCM {

private GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
private Context context;
private Activity activity;
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private int versionCode = 0;
private String versionName;
private static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";
private static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";
private static final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

/**
 * Substitute you own sender ID here. This is the project number you got
 * from the API Console, as described in "Getting Started."
 */
private String SENDER_ID;

private String registrationId;

public RegisterGCM(Context context, Activity activity, SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
                   int versionCode, String versionName, String SENDER_ID) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.context = context;
    this.sharedPreferences = sharedPreferences;
    this.versionCode = versionCode;
    this.versionName = versionName;
    this.SENDER_ID = SENDER_ID;
    checkServices();
}

private void checkServices() {
    // Check device for Play Services APK. If check succeeds, proceed with GCM registration.
    if (checkPlayServices()) {
        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
        registrationId = getRegistrationId(context);

        if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
            registerInBackground();
        }

    } else {
        Logger.log(RegisterGCM.class, "No valid Google Play Services APK found.", Logger.ERROR);
    }
}

/**
 * Check the device to make sure it has the Google Play Services APK. If
 * it doesn't, display a dialog that allows users to download the APK from
 * the Google Play Store or enable it in the device's system settings.
 */
public boolean checkPlayServices() {

    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);

    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {

        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {

            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, activity,
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Logger.log(RegisterGCM.class, "This device is not supported.", Logger.ERROR);
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Stores the registration ID and the app versionCode in the application's
 * {@code SharedPreferences}.
 *
 * @param context application's context.
 * @param regId   registration ID
 */
private void storeRegistrationId(Context context, String regId) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = sharedPreferences;
    int appVersion = UtilClass.getAppVersion(context);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, regId);
    editor.putInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, appVersion);
    editor.apply();
}

/**
 * Gets the current registration ID for application on GCM service, if there is one.
 * <p/>
 * If result is empty, the app needs to register.
 *
 * @return registration ID, or empty string if there is no existing
 * registration ID.
 */
private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {

    final SharedPreferences prefs = sharedPreferences;

    String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
    if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
        Logger.log(RegisterGCM.class, "Registration not found.", Logger.ERROR);
        return "";
    }
    // Check if app was updated; if so, it must clear the registration ID
    // since the existing regID is not guaranteed to work with the new
    // app version.
    int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    int currentVersion = UtilClass.getAppVersion(context);
    if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
        Logger.log(RegisterGCM.class, "App version changed.", Logger.ERROR);
        return "";
    }
    return registrationId;
}

/**
 * Registers the application with GCM servers asynchronously.
 * <p/>
 * Stores the registration ID and the app versionCode in the application's
 * shared preferences.
 */
private void registerInBackground() {

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                if (gcm == null) {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                }
                registrationId = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                // You should send the registration ID to your server over HTTP, so it
                // can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.


                WrapperUserRecorder wrapperUserRecorder = new WrapperUserRecorder(SENDER_ID,
                        registrationId, versionCode, versionName);
                new UserRecorder(wrapperUserRecorder, context).sendRegistrationIdToBackend();

                // Persist the regID - no need to register again.
                saveIDSendFlag(States.WAS_SEND);
                storeRegistrationId(context, registrationId);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
                // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
                // exponential back-off.
                Logger.log(RegisterGCM.class, "Expiry connecting to the server is out", Logger.ERROR);
                saveIDSendFlag(States.WAS_NOT_SEND);
            }
            return null;
        }

    }.execute();
}

private void saveIDSendFlag(boolean flag) {
    SharedPrefUtil.saveIDSendFlag(context, flag);
}

/**
 * Initialize and register app in GCM
 **/
public static RegisterGCM initGCM(Context context, Activity activity) {
    /**
     * Substitute you own sender ID here. This is the project number you got
     * from the API Console, as described in "Getting Started."
     */
    String SENDER_ID = context.getResources().getString(R.string.SENDER_ID);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
            RegisterGCM.class.getSimpleName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    int versionCode = 0;
    String versionName = null;

    try {
        versionCode = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).versionCode;
        versionName = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new RegisterGCM(context, activity, sharedPreferences, versionCode, versionName, SENDER_ID);
}
}
```

Инициацизация Google LogIn

```
public class GoogleImplementation {

private static Context context;
private ActivityAuthorization authorizationActivity;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private String tokenID;

public GoogleImplementation(Context context, ActivityAuthorization authorizationActivity) {
    GoogleImplementation.context = context;
    this.authorizationActivity = authorizationActivity;
}

public void initGoogleLogIn() {
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = getGoogleSignInOptions();
    mGoogleApiClient = getGoogleApiClient(gso);
    SignInButton btnSignIn = (SignInButton) authorizationActivity.findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(listener);
}

@NonNull
private GoogleSignInOptions getGoogleSignInOptions() {
    return new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(context.getResources().getString(R.string.server_id))
            .build();
}

@NonNull
private GoogleApiClient getGoogleApiClient(GoogleSignInOptions gso) {
    return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .enableAutoManage(authorizationActivity, listenerConnection)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
}

GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener listenerConnection =
        new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Logger.log(GoogleImplementation.class, "user have tried to logIn with Google but onConnectionFailed", Logger.ERROR);
    }
};

View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (!UtilClass.isNetworkConnection(context)) {
            UtilClass.showDialog(authorizationActivity.getFragmentManager(), new CallBackDialog());
        }

        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        authorizationActivity.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, States.GOOGLE_SIGNIN);
    }
};

public void getUserGoogleData(GoogleSignInResult result, GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    String name = getName(acct);
    tokenID = getTokenId(result);
    String personPhotoUrl = getPersonPhotoUrl(acct).toString();
    String personEmail = acct.getEmail();
    String personID = acct.getId();

    AuthorisationMaker.setPersonEmail(personEmail);
    AuthorisationMaker.setPersonId(personID);

    Logger.log(ActivityAuthorization.class, "name : " + name + " ID : " + tokenID +
            " personPhotoUrl " + personPhotoUrl + " personEmail : " + personEmail, Logger.ERROR);
}

public String getTokenID() {
    return tokenID;
}

private Uri getPersonPhotoUrl(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    return acct.getPhotoUrl();
}

private String getTokenId(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    String tokenId = null;
    GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = result.getSignInAccount();
    if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
        tokenId = googleSignInAccount.getIdToken();
    }
    return tokenId;
}

@Nullable
private String getName(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    String name = null;
    if (acct != null) {
        name = acct.getDisplayName();
    }
    return name;
}
}
```

**Файл конфигурации** сгенерировал по [этой ссылке](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fidentity%2Fsign-in%2Fandroid%2Fsign-in%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20Sign-In)

Вот что в файле

```
{
"project_info": {
"project_number": "2693226048",
"project_id": "ntzfr-17"
},
"client": [
{
  "client_info": {
    "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:2693224268:android:f802e670e6118171",
    "android_client_info": {
      "package_name": "com.fitingroom.newtimzone"
    }
  },
  "oauth_client": [
    {
      "client_id": "2693224248- o45crnrc6hnb200lhdam1uq95d72isi0.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      "client_type": 1,
      "android_info": {
        "package_name": "com.fitingroom.newtiezone",
        "certificate_hash": "5F6293FCD8F8FD026FF3B40F73CC1E5E7B239F"
      }
    },
    {
      "client_id": "2693226048-c2t8ndm60ak6u6n4rc0cjq8q3s8ltd.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      "client_type": 3
    }
  ],
  "api_key": [
    {
      "current_key": "ACrhi0BnxTnNRBsYyH451nZ7DSYaJc"
    }
  ],
  "services": {
    "analytics_service": {
      "status": 1
    },
    "appinvite_service": {
      "status": 1,
      "other_platform_oauth_client": []
    },
    "ads_service": {
      "status": 1
    }
  }
}
],
"configuration_version": "1"
}
```

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, ваш код авторизации.

Comment: @ИванПшеницын если я правильно понял, то это тот код. Дополнил в вопрос

Comment: хм. а где код логина в гугле? не вижу его тут.

Comment: @ИванПшеницын аа я подумал инициализация GCM ... Добавил код по кнопке

Comment: а конфиг-файл google-services.json вы сгенерили, с ним все в порядке? https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#get-config

Comment: @ИванПшеницын ну вроде, да... а как это проверить? Добавил к вопросу Я так понимаю, что этот файл конфигурации это единственное что связывает приложение и консоль разработчика? Я имею ввиду, что если я положу файл конфигурации который был сгенерирован под другим аккаунтом, то приложение будет привязано к другому аккаунту? Все зависит только от того какой файл конфигурации положить?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в том, что когда регистрировал другой аккаунт гугл разработчика, то делал это с другого компа и соотеветственно ключ SHA1 который указываю для подписи проекта на том компе отличается от ключа который генерируется на моем компе при билде...

Суть такая, ключ при регистрации приложения в гугл консоли должен быть сгенерирован на том же компе, на котором будет билдиться приложение...